# Transforming multiple objects

Tags: objects, transforms

How can I rotate several objects around their own center point?

If I select all using <kbd>A</kbd> then rotate, it rotates them based off of the center point of all the selected objects, instead of all the objects rotating around their own center point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the pivot point to individual elements.

[image]

This makes all the objects rotate around their own center point, instead of the averaged center point of all the selected objects.

Comment: Thank you very much! I apparently also needed to use local rotation [R] [Z] [Z]. now I could move all objects.

Comment: I'm happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Add an empty to your scene, then add a copy rotation constraint to all of the objects using the empty as target.

[image]

[image]